# C++ compiler errors in xamltypeinfo.g.cpp

Tags: c++, xaml, binding, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I must be missing something obvious but I'm not sure what.

I've created a blank C++ metro app and I've just added a model that I will bind to in my UI however I'm getting a range of compiler errors related to `xamltypeinfo.g.cpp` and I'm not sure what I've missed.

My header file looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyColor.h"

using namespace Platform;

namespace CppDataBinding
{
    [Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
    public ref class MyColor sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public:
        MyColor();
        ~MyColor();

        virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
        property Platform::String^ RedValue
        {
            Platform::String^ get()
            { 
                return _redValue;
            }
            void set(Platform::String^ value)
            {
                _redValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RedValue");
            }
        }

    protected:
        void RaisePropertyChanged(Platform::String^ name);

    private:
        Platform::String^ _redValue;
    };
}
```

and my cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyColor.h"

using namespace CppDataBinding;

MyColor::MyColor()
{
}

MyColor::~MyColor()
{
}

void MyColor::RaisePropertyChanged(Platform::String^ name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != nullptr)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, ref new  Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Nothing too tricky, but when I compile I get errors in `xamltypeinfo.g.cpp` indicating that `MyColor` is not defined in `CppDataBinding`.

The relevant generated code looks like this:

```
if (typeName == "CppDataBinding.MyColor")
{
    userType = ref new XamlUserType(this, typeName, GetXamlTypeByName("Object"));
    userType->Activator = ref new XamlTypeInfo::InfoProvider::Activator(
                            []() -> Platform::Object^ 
                            { 
                                return ref new CppDataBinding::MyColor(); 
                            });
    userType->AddMemberName("RedValue", "CppDataBinding.MyColor.RedValue");
    userType->SetIsBindable();
    xamlType = userType;
}
```

If I remove the `Bindable` attribute from `MyColor` the code compiles.

Can someone tell me what blindingly obvious thing I've missed so I can give myself a facepalm and fix the problem?

Comment: One blindingly obvious thing you've apparently missed is that whatever you're using here, it's not C++.

Comment: What error messages does the compiler emit?

Comment: what does this xor "^" do "Platform::String^" here?

Comment: @g24l:  This is C++/CX.  The ^ is a hat and declares a reference-counting smart pointer.

Comment: @g24l: There called [tracking references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Tracking_references).

Comment: @Jesse:  While the ^ is a tracking reference in C++/CLI, that's not what it is in C++/CX.  There's nothing to _track_ in C++/CX because objects do not move (i.e., there's no compacting garbage collector).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thanks for the insight, I haven't kept up with the times.

Comment: Jesse and JamesMcNellis , thanks :)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis First error is C2039: 'MyColor' : is not a member of 'CppDataBinding'.

Comment: Actually. I had exactly the same situation as yours and it also compiles if you include your header in App.xaml.h file.

Comment: @JesseGood u mad, bro?

Comment: @McGarnagle: Not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I made one small change and now it works.

I added

```
#include "MyColor.h"
```

to the `BlankPage.xaml.h` file, even though I haven't yet added any other references to `MyColor` and it now compiles.

I guess if you make something `[Bindable]` the header must be included in at least one xaml page for it to work.  A bindable type that is not referenced anywhere causes compiler errors.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Your analysis is correct.  This is a limitation of the XAML compiler.

Comment: I agree, this is definitely the case. I think in terms of cleanliness putting it in App.xaml.h might make more sense, seems like a good place for global-esque includes.

Comment: What if you're project is a custom control that doesn't have any *.xaml.h? So far polluting the pch.h is the way I can think of to make it work.

Comment: You should still have an App.xaml.h

Comment: @Tim You should NOT change pch.h frequently. It is for the precompiled header, presumably to allow C++ compiler to process macro faster. Every time you change it, VS rebuild the header which can be as big as 100MB, significantly defeat the original purpose.